# iOS 6: AVPlayerItem PresentationSize returning zero - (naturalSize method Deprecated on iOS 5)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, deprecated, core-video

Got this code:

```
videoSize = [[AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset] presentationSize];
```

// nslogs -> height: 000 width 000

And this deprecated:

```
videoSize = [asset naturalSize];
```

// nslogs -> height: 360 width 480

Why is this happening? I don't get it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Solved:

```
NSArray* allVideoTracks = [movieAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
if ([allVideoTracks count] > 0) {
AVAssetTrack* track = [[movieAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo]objectAtIndex:0];
CGSize size = [track naturalSize];
}
```

this made my day, hope it works for someone else...

Answer (score 0):

1. The `presentationSize` in `AVPlayerItem` may return a value of `CGSizeZero` when the player item is not ready to paly.[doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayeritem/1388962-presentationsize)
2. The `naturalSize` in `AVAsset` is depressed. [doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avasset/1508715-naturalsize)
3. Just like your code, it is recommended to use `naturalSize` and 
   `preferredTransform` in `AVAssetTrack`.

```
CGSize size = [[[movieAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] firstObject] naturalSize];
```